# Sorting values in a pandas column with type string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the values from highest to lowest which is pretty straightforward using the code but this is what I'm receiving when I do:

> Input:

`s.sort_values(by('1617 Entries & Exits), ascending = True)`

> Output:

`1617 Entries & Exits   Station Name
2559    NaN      Manchester United Football Ground
2558    NaN      Heathrow Terminals 2 & 3
2557    NaN      Heathrow Terminal 5
2556    NaN      Heathrow Terminal 4
1285    998,316  King's Lynn
1230    997,912  Irvine
915     996     Gainsborough Central
641     994      Cynghordy
1697    990,438  Ockendon
1540    99,704   Metheringham
847     99,610   Falmouth Docks
1294    99,484    Kintbury
2378    99,403,096  Waterloo
1642    99,394  Newcourt
34      99,380  Albrighton
2196    99,042  Summerston
2392    989,728 Wellingborough
1048    984,504 Hampton Wick
1677    984,332 North Wembley
2302    983,704 Trowbridge
1876    982,934 Rectory Road
296     982,592 Bootle New Strand
94      98,472  Ashburys
1282    98,290  Kinghorn
1474    98,234  Lytham
970     98,218  Gorebridge
1220    98,140  Insch
1978    979,098 Scarborough
494     978,986 Cheam
928     974 Garth (Powys)`

I was expecting it to return the highest number in that column '1617 Entries & Exits' which is actually 99,039,875 and ascend from there but it isn't happening.

Do I need to remove the missing values (NaN) first or change the data type of the column first?

The data type for that column is a series by the way: `pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the `thousands` argument when loading in `df`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., thousands=',')
```

This should read your second column in as a numeric column. Try sorting it now.

---

If that doesn't work, there's always the ugly fix:

```
df['1617 Entries & Exits'] = pd.to_numeric(
       df['1617 Entries & Exits'].astype(str).str.replace(',', ''),
       errors='coerce'
)
```

I hope it doesn't come to this.

Comment: This is super clear - unfortunately I had to do the ugly fix but it's all a learning curve. Thank you!